# viewWillLayoutSubviews getting called after applicationDidEnterBackground notification

Tags: ios, lifecycle

I'm having an issue where my app is crashing on sleep, and sometimes on home. I'm getting a `BAD_ACCESS` error in a thread called `gpus_ReturnNotPermittedKillClient`, which tells me that my app is making UI changes in the background, which to my understanding is a no-go. Therefore, I'm stepping through my code to see what happens on home / sleep, and I find that my breakpoint in my VC's `-viewWillLayoutSubviews` method is getting hit AFTER the breakpoints in the `-applicationWillResignActive` and `-appplicationDidEnterBackground` notifications (in which I'm attempting to stop all updates from an asynchronous callback function).

That doesn't seem to make any sense. From the application's perspective, if it's not cool to do UI updates in the background, why call `viewWillLayoutSubviews` after you're in the background?

EDIT: It appears to do this even when my app doesn't crash. Could it just be lldb getting things out of order?

Comment: Are you running an iOS 7 beta?

Comment: Nope. I'm running iOS 6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you simply need to be tolerant of this.  Per this [tech note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1766/_index.html), you can't do any GLES rendering in the background. My recommendation would be for your app to set a flag when `applicationWillResignActive` is called, and then before doing any rendering work you check that flag and don't do the work (and perhaps just call `-setNeedsDisplay` on the view so that if your app becomes active again it will know to draw that view).  You seem troubled by the fact that `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is getting called "late", but I don't see how that really matters.  (i.e. layout != rendering) I would be surprised if your view's `-drawRect:` method were getting called after `applicationDidEnterBackground` but I would still say that it would be your responsibility to check a flag and not render if your app is in the background.

Comment: Ah that helps, I didn't realize the distinction between changing the layout and rendering. Thanks!